# Would an AC EMI filter capacitors contribute to inrush current?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, rectifier, power-factor-correction, inrush-current

Shown below is an EMI filter for an AC input. My doubt is **when I analyse the inrush current, should I be considering the contribution due to all three capacitors?**

a) Differential mode capacitors

b) Common mode capacitors

c) Load capacitors ( In our case, the load is rectifier with bulk caps at the output)

Since these currents might not be in phase, the straightforward addition may not be feasible*. Iam not sure **how can the net effect be calculated?**

(*I guess, the 90 degree phase difference between AC voltage (across) and current through a capacitor would not be applicable during inrush duration (Since the 90 phase difference is a steady state phenomenon). Please confirm.)

Also would I be getting different inrush values if I measure the phase leg or nuteral leg of AC supply - depending on the additive/subtractive nature of common mode current?

**PS:** In our existing design we are addressing only the inrush current due to rectifier o/p caps. Iam not sure why the inrush due to EMI filter caps is omitted.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to simulate it?

Comment: @winny: Unfortunately no. I will try once I get the time to develop the model.

Comment: You already have a model, the schematic you posted. It should be good enough for 99 % of cases, save for EMI compliance at high frequencies.

Comment: @DivyaK.S are we done here? Do you have an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *My doubt is when I analyse the inrush current, should I be considering
> the contribution due to all three capacitors?*

and

> *In our existing design we are addressing only the inrush current due
> to rectifier o/p caps. I am not sure why the inrush due to EMI filter
> caps is omitted.*

Compared to the value of the bulk capacitor used in most power supplies I expect that the contribution to inrush from the EMI filter capacitors is negligible. However, if you wish to analyse inrush and include these capacitors then that's your call.

> *Since these currents might not be in phase, the straightforward
> addition may not be feasible. I am not sure how can the net effect be
> calculated?*

I wouldn't hesitate to use a simulator.

> *I guess, the 90 degree phase difference between AC voltage (across)
> and current through a capacitor would not be applicable during inrush
> duration (Since the 90 phase difference is a steady state phenomenon).
> Please confirm.*

Correct.

> *Also would I be getting different inrush values if I measure the phase
> leg or neutral leg of AC supply - depending on the
> additive/subtractive nature of common mode current?*

Yes you would because neutral is tied to earth at some point and that imbalances the  capacitors on the load side of the filter. My best advice is this: use a simulator.